# Stacktrace in erlang tracer

Tags: erlang, elixir, trace, beam

Is it possible to return a stacktrace in a trace? I'm using `:dbg.tp/3` and `:dbg.tracer/2` to get a trace along with the calling module. I tried `caller` function (see in docs: https://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html) but it gives me the very next call from the stack (which is `{:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6}`), what I need is the first function that is defined in my project.

For context, handler function passed to `tracer/2`:

```
    handler_fun = fn {:trace, _pid, :call, {_m, _f, _a}, dump}, _ignored ->
      IO.puts(dump)
    end
```

and the tp call (for now I just use process dump that gives me the stack in binary, but I would like to get it in a form that I can interpret in code and not parse it):

```
:dbg.tp(module, :_, [{:_, [], [{:message, {:process_dump}}]}])
```

I'm open to using a different tool than tracing/dbg.

Comment: Hey, have you found an answer to this by any chance?